# What kinds of questions should/shouldn't I ask here?

Tags: discussion, faq, allowed-topics

What are the kinds of questions I can ask here?

- Which questions are considered good and on-topic questions on this site?
- On the other hand, what kinds of questions shouldn't I ask here?
- Which questions are considered off-topic, and out of the scope of this site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), a Q&A site regarding Japanese anime and manga.

### Good questions are

- Questions which can be answered with facts, or plot items which were already confirmed.
- Questions which directly ask about a specific manga and/or anime.
- Questions which directly ask about anime and/or manga in general.
- Questions which directly ask about canonical events in a specific anime and/or manga.

### Bad questions are

- Questions about future events. They cannot be correctly answered, and they end up as one of two cases:

  1. Either the future event never happens, and the question remains unanswered.
  2. Or the event happens, and then the question is obsolete.
- Questions which would end up soliciting debate:

  - "Who would win? X or Y?"
  - "Which anime is better? X or Y?"
- Questions which don't ask directly about any sort of anime/manga, or anime/manga in general.
- Questions that can *only* be answered by assuptions not supported with *any* facts, e.g.:

  - If Spike from Cowboy Bebop had Sharingan, would the anime have ended differently?

Comment: Also what about questions like "What anime series is like X?"

Comment: @grasshopper: It's a community wiki for a reason, feel free to edit and add it yourself!

Comment: @grasshopper: I [opened a question](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/117/20) about this, so we can be clear about it.

Comment: "*plot items which were already confirmed*" how is the question asker supposed to know whether it is already confirmed? And if it is not yet (clearly) confirmed/known it still might result in debate